# Where should I position the correlating conjunction relative to the infinitive?

Tags: conjunctions, infinitives

I am proofreading the following sentence:

- *They inspired her to produce not only her zine and blog but to create a whole new scene in New Orleans.*

I am thinking it should rather be written as follows:

- *They inspired her not only to produce her zine and blog but also to create a whole new scene in New Orleans.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your version is grammatical and idiomatic (ie not an unusual usage). I'd say the first is unacceptable, probably ungrammatical ... certainly better reworded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the “not only . . . but also” construction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123795/how-to-use-the-not-only-but-also-construction) (see tchrist's answer).

Comment: You are correct about parallelism. But you can share the infinitive **to** particle: *They inspired her **to** not only produce her zine and blog but also create a whole new scene in New Orleans.*

Answer (score 1):

Your version is better than the original.

The reason is that the original should only be used if the verb "produced" carried the whole phrase, e.g.

> They inspired her to not only produce A and B but also C.

But this is not the case here, and in fact a new verb - "create" - is introduced.

> Q: What was she inspired to?
> A: two things: 
> 1) produce A and B
> 2) create C

Because of parallelism, your version is preferred.